# Why is "The Most Merciful, The Most Beneficent" sometimes written "The Merciful, The Beneficent"?

Tags: quran-translation, asma-ul-husna

We know that Allah is The Most Merciful, The Most Beneficent. Why, in some translations, is it written The Merciful, The Beneficent? Why is "Most" not written?

Comment: Wa Alaikum As Salam. In the original Arabic, the word 'most' is not there. It is just "The Beneficent, The Merciful". The article "The" (in Arabic 'Al') already implies that He is Unique in it, Perfect and Most High in these categories. So the most is redundant. BUT, saying it either way is fine.. with or without the 'Most' added. Same thing either way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in some people's names we find Al Hakeem, Al Samee, etc. instead of just Hakeem or just Samee. Isn't it impermissible to use these names for Allah's servants?

Comment: Yes, that is impermissible.

Comment: What about Luqman al-Hakeem or Assim al-Hakeem then?

Comment: Calling a person 'the wise one' has a different meaning than when used for Allah. Per IslamQA: "Some Hanafi fuqaha’ confirmed that when they said: Calling people by names of Allaah which are found in the book of Allaah, such as al-‘Aliy (high, exalted), al-Kabeer (great), al-Rasheed (wise), al-Badee’ (innovator or originator), is permissible, because they are names that may be shared by Allaah and people, but their meaning when used for people is different from their meaning when used for Allaah, may He be glorified and exalted. End quote."

Comment: Because Allah is the source of all beneficence and mercy.  A 'most' adverb is irrelevant